# Can't achieve height:100% when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to figure out for the longest while why I couldn't get a table at 100% height although all it's parents were at 100%. Playing around I found it worked once I removed jQuery mobile from the site. After that I created a bare bones version of it and actually got the same results. I have no idea why this happens. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<table class="container">
   <tr style="height:15%;"><td>Menu Goes here</td></tr>
   <tr style="height:85%;"><td>Content Goes here</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boilerplate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:solid 2px red;
}
tr {
    border:solid 2px blue;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using a custom jQuery Mobile build but I get the same results even when I use Google's CND.

Any idea why this happens and how to work around it?

EDIT:

http://ramiroproductions.businesscatalyst.com/test.html - barebones version
http://ramiroproductions.businesscatalyst.com/aboutus.html - actual site

Comment: So it seems to be working for me (I am not including your boilerplate.css or jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css). [Check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/zo3pnncp/)

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper That's the thing. It doesn't work when I add jQuery Mobile. Then it behaves as if the height was set to auto

Comment: Mind tossing up a jsfiddle or link with everything thats being loaded?

Comment: Which widgets have you included in your custom build? Have you added auto-init too?

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper I updated the question... have a look.

Comment: @Omar I don't recall.

Comment: Your `<div data-role="page">` needs to be 100% as well, thats what is stopping your `.container'

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper Haven't explored that but refer to the answer below. JQM was actually adding a wrapper to the content. Once that was set at 100% height, all was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`!important`** to make sure that any other css is not overriding the height property.
Also check by doing an inspect element to see if your css is applied or it is <strike>striked out</strike>.

**Update:**
For the height property to work correctly if given in percentage you have to make sure that its parent has been given a height. Jquery mobile is adding its own div wrapper on your html which is not having height 100%. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v0u2opca/1) for solution.

Comment: for the height property to work correctly if given in percentage you have to make sure that its parent has been given a height.

Comment: Yes but as far as I can see all its parents are 100%

Comment: I just tried a demo on jsfiddle. jquery mobile is adding its own div wrapper on your html which is not having height 100%. see here : http://jsfiddle.net/v0u2opca/1/

Comment: Ahh. I see. It works now. I never found that extra div. Thanks.

Comment: @coding, mind updating your answer to the actual solution found in the comments?